# On Asp.net core how to trigger action or method

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I working on Asp.net core project and need on request on one controllers action trigger some method and don't wait for it to finish but respond to caller immediately. How can I accomplish it?

Comment: `Task.Run(() => SomeMethod());`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can certainly use a Task for this. However, this isn't a good idea because if ASP.NET recycles, your work will disappear.

```
Task.Run(() => FireAndForgetMethod());
```

A more robust and safe choice is to use something like [Hangfire.io](http://hangfire.io/) which relies on reliable storage.

```
BackgroundJob.Enqueue(() => FireAndForgetMethod());
```